# ExifInterface GPS not read on Android Q/10

Tags: android, exif, androidx, android-10.0, android-exifinterface

I'm having the issue that Android 10 can't read GPS information from my jpeg files. The exact same files are working on Android 9.
I tried the ExifInterface (androidx) which returns null, as well as apache commons imaging which is saying "GPSLatitude: Invalid rational (0/0), Invalid rational (0/0)".
Other exif information like the rating or XPKeywords are read correctly.

How to fix that?

Test code:

```
import androidx.exifinterface.media.ExifInterface;
ExifInterface exif2 = new ExifInterface(is);
double[] latLngArray = exif2.getLatLong();
```

getLatLong Implementation:

```
public double[] getLatLong() {
    String latValue = getAttribute(TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
    String latRef = getAttribute(TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
    String lngValue = getAttribute(TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
    String lngRef = getAttribute(TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);
    if (latValue != null && latRef != null && lngValue != null && lngRef != null) {
        try {
            double latitude = convertRationalLatLonToDouble(latValue, latRef);
            double longitude = convertRationalLatLonToDouble(lngValue, lngRef);
            return new double[] {latitude, longitude};
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Latitude/longitude values are not parseable. " +
                    String.format("latValue=%s, latRef=%s, lngValue=%s, lngRef=%s",
                            latValue, latRef, lngValue, lngRef));
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

All getAttribute calls are returning null on Android Q/10. On Android 9 it is working. My test photo does contain GPS information.
Even Android itself was unable to index the GPS location into their media store. The field is null as well in their database. I transferred the test photo via mail.

Comment: How are you opening those files? File access in Android 10 has changed...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned [in developer android](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped#photos-location-info), now, on Android 10, the location embed on image files is not directly available to the apps:

> Because this location information is sensitive, however, Android 10 by default hides this information from your app if it uses scoped storage.

On that same link, you can check how to fix:

1. Request the `ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION` permission in your app's manifest.
2. From your MediaStore object, call `setRequireOriginal()`, passing in the URI of the photograph, as shown in the following code snippet:

Code snippet:

```
Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        cursor.getString(idColumnIndex));

// Get location data from the ExifInterface class.
photoUri = MediaStore.setRequireOriginal(photoUri);
InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
if (stream != null) {
    ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(stream);
    // Don't reuse the stream associated with the instance of "ExifInterface".
    stream.close();
} else {
    // Failed to load the stream, so return the coordinates (0, 0).
    latLong = new double[2];
}
```

Note how they are now using `Uri`, `InputStream` (and also `FileDescriptor`) to access the file since now, you can't access a file using its file path.

Comment: The MediaStore still returns null. "This constant was deprecated in API level 29. location details are no longer indexed for privacy reasons, and this value is now always null." --> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns

Comment: You have to read using one of the new methods: (ExifInterface.getLatLong(float[]) for example)

Comment: the link no longer works. what's idColumnIndex and cursor ?

Comment: Can setRequireOriginal() also be used to amend an Uri which is passed via Intent for sharing a photo to another app? See issue for further details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68442139/exif-location-data-removed-when-sharing-photo-via-intent

Comment: Not working solution! exifInterface.getLatLong(latLong) returns 0.0 values for latitude and longitude always. But coordinates are exists in image - in image viewer I can see this info. Anybody can help with issue?

Comment: Anyone found solution? Not working in Android 12

Comment: @KrutikaChotara were you able to find a solution for Android 12?

Comment: Same for me, not working in Android 12. MediaStore.setRequireOriginal(uri) adds to the uri "?requireOriginal=1" and in getContentResolver().openInputStream it throws an exception "Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A61?requireOriginal=1 from pid=26281, uid=10151 requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs". But the permission is granted and the same code works in Android 10, 11, 13, 14.