# Getting null values on ExifInterface when trying to get Latitude and Longitude data

Tags: android, kotlin

My goal is to make Camera2 API to take a new photo and with that photo to have exif data implemented by code, using the ExifInterface. I am stumbled to a small issue though. When I run the app, it runs correctly when I press the capture button and saves the JPEG file that is needed, although when the code tries to add the exif data, it says **null**. I added everything I need which are the `setAttribute()` to set up new data and override the data that I need to add and `getAttribute()` to display it with `Log.e()` to see the results. But the result on the exif shows that is null. I've made some calculations about the exif data in a separate class to make sure to make it comfortable for me, some people would do on the same class, but made it separately. This is the message in the Logcat:

```
E/LATITUDE: null
E/LONGITUDE: null
D/Camera2BasicFragment: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.camera2apikotlin4/files/pic.jpg
```

This is the photo and a screenshot of the exif data, literally blank and not saved:
[The picture that took with the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deBXU.jpg)
[The screenshot that shows with Exif Pilot the exif data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We7qq.jpg)

This is where the `file` variable comes from and where it saves:

```
private lateinit var file: File   

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        //val PIC_FILE_NAME = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy-HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"
        val PIC_FILE_NAME = "pic.jpg"
        file = File(requireActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null), PIC_FILE_NAME)
    }
```

Where it's starting the capture process:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        private fun process(result: CaptureResult) {
            when (state) {
                STATE_PREVIEW -> Unit // Do nothing when the camera preview is working normally.
                STATE_WAITING_LOCK -> capturePicture(result)
                STATE_WAITING_PRECAPTURE -> {
                    // CONTROL_AE_STATE can be null on some devices
                    val aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE)
                    if (aeState == null ||
                        aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE ||
                        aeState == CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_STATE_FLASH_REQUIRED) {
                        state = STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE
                    }
                }
                STATE_WAITING_NON_PRECAPTURE -> {
                    // CONTROL_AE_STATE can be null on some devices
                    val aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE)
                    if (aeState == null || aeState != CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_PRECAPTURE) {
                        state = STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN
                        captureStillPicture()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        private fun capturePicture(result: CaptureResult) {
            val afState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE)
            if (afState == null) {
                captureStillPicture()
            } else if (afState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_FOCUSED_LOCKED
                || afState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AF_STATE_NOT_FOCUSED_LOCKED) {
                // CONTROL_AE_STATE can be null on some devices
                val aeState = result.get(CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE)
                if (aeState == null || aeState == CaptureResult.CONTROL_AE_STATE_CONVERGED) {
                    state = STATE_PICTURE_TAKEN
                    captureStillPicture()
                } else {
                    runPrecaptureSequence()
                }
            }
        }

        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        override fun onCaptureProgressed(session: CameraCaptureSession,
                                         request: CaptureRequest,
                                         partialResult: CaptureResult) {
            process(partialResult)
        }

        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
        override fun onCaptureCompleted(session: CameraCaptureSession,
                                        request: CaptureRequest,
                                        result: TotalCaptureResult) {
            process(result)
        }

    }
```

This is the separated code geoDegree():

```
package com.example.camera2apikotlin4

import androidx.exifinterface.media.ExifInterface

class geoDegree {
    private var valid: Boolean = true
    var latitudeFloat: Double = 0.0
    var longitudeFloat: Double = 0.0

    fun geoDegree(exif: ExifInterface) {
        val attrLATITUDE = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE)
        val attrLATITUDE_REF = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF)
        val attrLONGITUDE = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE)
        val attrLONGITUDE_REF = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF)

        if (
            (attrLATITUDE != null) &&
            (attrLATITUDE_REF != null) &&
            (attrLONGITUDE != null) &&
            (attrLONGITUDE_REF != null))
            {
                //Telling the code that the validation is true
                valid = true

                //If the reference of the latitude is equals to the letter N, it will convert it to degrees, else it will be none
                if(attrLATITUDE_REF == "N") {
                    latitudeFloat = convertToDegree(attrLATITUDE)
                } else {
                    0 - convertToDegree(attrLATITUDE)
                }

                //If the reference of the longitude is equals to the letter E, it will convert it to degrees, else it will be none
                if(attrLONGITUDE_REF == "E") {
                    longitudeFloat = convertToDegree(attrLONGITUDE)
                } else {
                    0 - convertToDegree(attrLONGITUDE)
                }
        }
    }

    //The method function that converting the degrees, using the list of strings
    private fun convertToDegree(stringDMS: String): Double {
        val result: Double?
        val DMS: List<String> = stringDMS.split(",")

        //Values in degrees
        val stringD: List<String> = DMS[0].split("/")
        val D0 = stringD[0].toDouble()
        val D1 = stringD[1].toDouble()
        val FloatD: Double = D0 / D1

        //Values in minutes
        val stringM = DMS[1].split("/")
        val M0 = stringM[0].toDouble()
        val M1 = stringM[1].toDouble()
        val FloatM: Double = M0 / M1

        //Values in seconds
        val stringS = DMS[2].split("/")
        val S0 = stringS[0].toDouble()
        val S1 = stringS[1].toDouble()
        val FloatS = S0 / S1

        /**Overall results to display on, when combining the Float Degrees
         * and calculating with Minutes about 60, Seconds with 3600 and overall to be as Float type
         **/
        result = (FloatD + (FloatM/60) + (FloatS/3600))

        return result
    }

    fun isValid(): Boolean {
        return valid
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return ("$latitudeFloat, $longitudeFloat")
    }

    fun getLatitudeE6(): Int {
        return (latitudeFloat.times(1000000)).toInt()
    }

    fun getLongitudeE6(): Int {
        return (longitudeFloat.times(1000000)).toInt()
    }
}
```

This is the main code that is in the `imageCapture`:

```
/**
     * Capture a still picture. This method should be called when we get a response in
     * [.captureCallback] from both [.lockFocus].
     */
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    private fun captureStillPicture() {
        try {
            if (activity == null || cameraDevice == null) return
            val rotation = requireActivity().windowManager.defaultDisplay.rotation

            // This is the CaptureRequest.Builder that we use to take a picture.
            val captureBuilder = cameraDevice?.createCaptureRequest(
                CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE)?.apply {
                imageReader?.surface?.let { addTarget(it) }

                // Sensor orientation is 90 for most devices, or 270 for some devices (eg. Nexus 5X)
                // We have to take that into account and rotate JPEG properly.
                // For devices with orientation of 90, we return our mapping from ORIENTATIONS.
                // For devices with orientation of 270, we need to rotate the JPEG 180 degrees.
                set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION,
                    (ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation) + sensorOrientation + 270) % 360)

                // Use the same AE and AF modes as the preview.
                set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)


            }?.also { setAutoFlash(it) }

            val captureCallback = object : CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

                override fun onCaptureCompleted(session: CameraCaptureSession,
                                                request: CaptureRequest,
                                                result: TotalCaptureResult) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Saved: $file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d(TAG, file.toString())
                    unlockFocus()
                }
            }.apply {
                val exif = ExifInterface(file)
                geoDegree().geoDegree(exif)

                exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, "${geoDegree().getLatitudeE6()}")
                exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, "${geoDegree().getLongitudeE6()}")
                exif.saveAttributes()
                geoDegree().isValid()

                val exifLatitude = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE)
                val exifLongitude = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE)
                Log.e("LATITUDE", "$exifLatitude")
                Log.e("LONGITUDE", "$exifLongitude")
            }

            captureSession?.apply {
                stopRepeating()
                abortCaptures()
                captureBuilder?.build()?.let { capture(it, captureCallback, null) }
            }
        } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString())
        }

    }
```

Any tip, trick, advice, anything really to help out the small issue to be fixed. It's maybe easy for you, but I am still learning on how to do it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @blackapps I apologize for that, now the code is in the post.

Comment: We cannot see where you use that `file` variable. So how can you log that something is saved in that file?

Comment: @blackapps Ok so I edited again the code, so the ```file``` is made outside as a private variable with a type File, then it's used in the override method ```onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)```, to make it where it suppose to save the file, because it's used and casted within a Activity Fragment.

Comment: We still do not see that you use that file instance somewhere to take a picture.

Comment: @blackapps Ohhh I really apologize for wasting your time, I'm really am still new to the platform, plus on how to explain and yet I am still confusing you, wait for atleast 10 minutes and refresh for the code on where the picture is taken. I'm really sorry.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68442139/exif-location-data-removed-when-sharing-photo-via-intent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the issue is happening in Android API >= 29 then consider that from 29 and above the geo location is redacted as this is now considered sensitive information. This means that if you wish to read the geo location back, then you need to first request the original Uri, and use the obtained Uri with ExifInterface or opening a stream, otherwise there is no way to get the geo location back:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#setRequireOriginal(android.net.Uri)

```
originalUri = MediaStore.setRequireOriginal(photoUri)
```

In addition you will need to also have/**request** the [ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION) permission. Without it your app has no right to read the geo location.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have code that uses the ImageReader you set as the capture target and saves an image to the File you've set up, the main thing I see missing is that you're not putting any location information into the JPEG image.

The camera API does not have direct access to location information; if you want EXIF metadata with location in it in the final JPEG, you have to give it to the camera API yourself first:
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest#jpeg_gps_location

For that, you need to get a Location object (which requires one of the LOCATION permissions), and at that point, I'm not sure if you really need to parse the EXIF for a location instead of just using Location object to begin with.